# SQL-server bulk insert with modified values

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert values from a scv file into a table in SQL server.

```
BULK
INSERT UserData
FROM 'c:\users.scv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

The users.scv file has userdata like this:

```
firstname, lastname, age, location
```

However my table has the following columns

```
username, age, location
```

When i do my bulk insert i want to combine firstname and lastname as the username in the table, `"lastname, firstname"`.

How do i do this?

Comment: You need to create a format file. See here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Import your data in to a staging table (that has the 4 columns). Then push the data in to the destination table.